# import panoramaGL on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, import, dependencies, 360-panorama-viewer

I've a problem importing PanoramaGL library in my project.
this is the library https://github.com/zarelaky/panoramagl-android/tree/master/PanoramaGL

there are instructions for importing on Eclipse but i cant import on Android Studio. I've tryied import from source or from .jar files but without success.

Anyone can explain me step by step how to import this library?

thank you!